# Order Guarantee with Sparking Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to get some change event from Kafka that I would like to propagate downstream in another system. However the `Change` order matters. Hence I wonder what is the appropriate way to do that with some Spark transformation in the middle.

The only thing I see is to loose the parallelism and make the DStream on one partition. Maybe there is a way to do operation in parallel and bring everything back in one partition and then send it to the external system or back in Kafka and then use a Kafka Sink for the matter.

What approach can I try?

Comment: Kafka guarantees ordering within a partition, i.e. if your change event has a unique ID, then any data for it will always be in the same partition -- and hence you'll have an order guarantee.  Only if you are worrying about global ordering -- across different change events, i.e. different IDs -- you'd need to go down the partition=1 route.

Answer (score 0):

In a distributed environment, with some form of cashing/buffering at most layer, message generated from same machine may reach back-end in different order. Also the definition of order is subjective. Implementing a global definition of order will be restrictive (may not be correct) for the data as a whole.

So, Kafka is meant for keeping the data in order in the order of put but partition comes as a catch!!! Partition defines the level of parallelism per topic.

Typically, the level of abstraction at which kafka is kept, it should not bother much about order. It should be optimised for maximum throughput, where partitioning will come handy!!! Consider ordering just a side effect of supporting streaming!!!

Now, what ever logic ensures, that data is put in to kafka in order, that makes more sense in your application (spark job).

Comment: Yes I get that, however the question is how to ensure that things get be put in order in KAFKA from my spark job. Is the only solution, to actually reparation the data in one partition and then output them in kafka. Meaning the transformation of the data can be done in parallel, but then, a repartition must happen, to put everything back in one partition, and then push ine D kafka. The problem is, am i sure that all the RDD will be treated in the order that they appear in the DStream ?